# Swatch on listing page but image on Product Page

Tags: swatches, color-swatches

First time posting here. Magento 2.4.0 I am trying to show color swatches on the product listing page but an image of the configurable products on the product page. By selecting use product image as swatch if possible I can see product images on both the product page and listing page but I don't want the product images on the listing page I just want color swatches as product images looks really messy on the listing. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same Question.

I'm Stuck on the part where magento decides if it will be a image or a text.
I think it is controlled around the following code:

```
/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php @ line 434
```

if somebody had a solution or a direction to look further in, please let us know.